# FTP file to specific path on server

Tags: mac, command-line, ftp

I try to FTP a file with a one liner in a shell from a mac to a folder on my server.
Doing the same in the FTP-Shell is not a problem for me, but doing this in one line is not possible to me.

I even do not succeed with the following simple connecttest, which I guess is standard on every other system:

```
ftp name:password@mysite
```

How to transfer a file in one commandline with following info?

```
filename: <file>
server:<server>
username:<username>
password:<password>
pathonserver:<path>
```

`ftp <username>:<password>@<server> "cd <path>;put <file>"` ?

Comment: does `ftp ftp://<user>:<pass>@<server>/<path>` work ?

Comment: Yes that works. Thanks, thats a good start. And how to put the file ?

Comment: It's `ftp -u ftp://<user>:<pass>@<server>/<path> /path/to/file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload a file to the specific path using `ftp` command you have to:

```
ftp -u ftp://<user>:<pass>@<server>/<path> /path/to/file
```

From `man ftp`:

> ```
>  -u URL file [...]
>              Upload files on the command line to URL where URL is one of
>              the ftp URL types as supported by auto-fetch (with an
>              optional target filename for single file uploads), and file
>              is one or more local files to be uploaded.
> ```

For `auto-fetch` URLs also look into `man ftp` under `AUTO-FETCHING FILES` section.